# How to reinstall all installed packages with zypper

Tags: command-line, pipe, rpm, zypper, reinstall

How do I tell `zypper` to reinstall all currently installed packages?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can reinstall all currently installed packages by this command:

```
zypper in -f $(rpm -q -a --qf '%{NAME} ')
```

Maybe this information will be useful.

Comment: You can add a query to only reinstall certain packages. For example, reinstall all python packages only: `zypper in -f $(rpm -qa python* --qf '%{NAME} ')`

Answer (score 5):

I would add --no-recommends as option, to not install additional packages.

```
zypper in --no-recommends -f $(rpm -qa --qf '%{NAME} ')
```

also consider --download-in-advance , to avoid missing availability causing the install to interrupt.

```
zypper in --no-recommends --download-in-advance -f $(rpm -qa --qf '%{NAME} ')
```